# trim() not working for input field validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used this `inputNameVal.trim();` inside a click (submit) function

it doesn't work by using

```
if(name !=""){
//passed
}
```

the user can put insert blank data

Comment: can you share how `inputNameVal` is created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a trim function that can be used like:

```
var trimmedValue = $.trim(inputNameVal);
```

Also, inputNameVal.trim() is a function call that does not modify the value of the string, you'd have to have something like:

```
inputNameVal = inputNameVal.trim()
```

if `String.trim` is not defined for your browser [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) says you can define it yourself like:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`String.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) is not known by all browsers (see at the bottom of the page).

As you tagged this question with jQuery, you can use [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) like this :

```
$.trim(inputNameVal)
```